# How to run just arbitrary native query in Spring-Data-JPA environment?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, spring-transactions, nativequery

I need to convert "horizontal" data representation into "vertical" one. For this I need to run INSERT query multiple times, one for each column of source table.

I can't annotate dozens of `@Query` or something.

Can I just run some native query somewhere in the service?

**UPDATE**

I wrote the following:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CopyFromInPopulationToBinValues extends Op {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

...

   @Override
   public void run() {

      String queryString, queryTemplate;
      Bin bin;
      Query query;

      em.joinTransaction();

      //binValueRepo.deleteByStatId(1);
      queryString = "delete from bin_values where id in (select bv.id from bin_values bv inner join bin b on bv.bin_id = b.id where b.stat_id = ?1)";
      query = em.createNativeQuery(  queryString );
      query.executeUpdate();
```

surpisingly, `@PersistenceContext` annotation worked and I got not-null `em`.

Unfortunately, I can't find valid combination of `@Transactional`, `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation and `em.joinTransaction()` call so that query worked.

If I don't have `em.joinTransaction()` I get

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

on query execute. If I have it, I get

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'joinTransaction'
```

on this call.

If I apply `@Transactional` to the class or to the `run()` method, I have the same situation (no effect).

If I apply `@EnableTransactionManagement` (to database config) without any `@Transactional` annotations (to this class), it also has no effect.

And if I apply `@EnableTransactionManagement` along with any `@Transactional`, I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '....CopyFromInPopulationToBinValues'
```